# android find latitude longitude of a point in particular direction from current location

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android app in which I want to find the latitude & longitude of a point at a certain distance and in a particular direction (north/south/east/west) from the current location.

Any ideas on how this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you have your long, lat values you could just add to them.  however i cannot give you the formulas since my math isnt the best and as for math like this im not even going to try and figure out the equation.  heres a few links though to get you started, remember its the math not the code thats gonna help ya

http://sgowtham.net/blog/2009/08/04/php-calculating-distance-between-two-locations-given-their-gps-coordinates/

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?656315-Adding-Distance-To-GPS-Coordinates-To-Get-Bounding-Box

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?482470-Find-the-closest-location-near-your-address

Comment: I have the latitude longitude of only the start point and only have a distance and bearing of destination; I want to find the latitude longitude of destination

Comment: right, sooo.  (way oversimplified example:) your at kmart at lat:2 long:3.  you want to display a point that is 20miles north of that kmart.  so you would add 20 to say lat.  so now the point is at lat:22 long:3.   like i said you will need to figure out the math of how to calculate distance in a direction from your current point, but it should work